# Multi domain on my dedicated server with Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

I setup a server with Ubuntu 10.04 server edition. 
It's works for a long time with a single domain name. Now i want to add another domain wich will pointed to a new directory.

I tried to change my Apache2 configuration but it does not seems to work properly.

Here is my  /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
</VirtualHost>
```

here is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

**.***.133.29   sd-***.****.fr sd-****
**.***.133.29   mediousgame.com

 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
 ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 ****::0 ip6-localnet
 ****: :0 ip6-mcastprefix
 ****::1 ip6-allnodes
 ****::2 ip6-allrouters
 ****::3 ip6-allhosts
```

With this configuration when i try to access to mydomain it redirect to the /var/www/ content. 
Do you have any idea to redirect to the right folder ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the following example taken from [apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), it seems you are missing `ServerName` line from the first virtual host. Try to make your configuration similar to this (of course, you can keep the other directives like `<directory>`).

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to setup the right DNS entries or at least modify your hosts file to resolve both domains to the correct IP address.

Comment: My first Virtualhost don't have any name, it show some content after redirection... Just added my /etc/hosts